# Dynamic adding of checkboxes in asp.net using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-controls

I am trying to add two sets of `checkboxes` in my *`asp.net`* project. There I am doing this:

on page load:

```
 public static CheckBox[] chck = new CheckBox[100];
 public static CheckBox[] chckbx = new CheckBox[100];
```

and i have a functions:

```
  public void generatecheckbox1()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
    {
        chck[i] = new CheckBox();
        chck[i].ID = chck + Convert.ToString(i);
        chck[i].Text = chck + Convert.ToString(i);
        pnlcom1.Controls.Add(chck[i]);
        pnlcom1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

        chckbx[i] = new CheckBox();
        chckbx[i].ID = chckbx + Convert.ToString(i);
        chckbx[i].Text = chckbx + Convert.ToString(i);
        pnlcom2.Controls.Add(chckbx[i]);
        pnlcom2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
    }
}
```

and i am calling this function here:

```
protected void ddluserwebser_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddluserwebser.SelectedItem.Text == "Custom")
    {
        generatecheckbox1();

    }
}
```

The problem is i am getting an error page like this:

[image]

its saying this:

*`Multiple controls with the same ID 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox[]0' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.`*

But I am assigning different `ids..` what should i do?

Comment: Do you call `generatecheckbox1` only once or multiple times maybe on postback?

Comment: i am calling it only once

Comment: don't **chck** here `chck[i].ID = chck + Convert.ToString(i);`
 needs to be  `chck[i].ID = "chck" + Convert.ToString(i);`

Comment: @legendinmaking that worked ... thanks write that as answer then i will be able to accept it ... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't chck here `chck[i].ID = chck + Convert.ToString(i);` needs to be
 `chck[i].ID = "chck" + Convert.ToString(i);`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're creating two checkboxes in one loop iteration with the same id. That's not allowed in ASP.NET when they are in the same `NamingContainer`([`Panel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.aspx) doesn't implement [`INamingContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer.aspx)).

So change it to(note the `string.Format` part):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
{
    chck[i] = new CheckBox();
    chck[i].ID = string.Format("chk_1_{0}", i);
    chck[i].Text = chck + Convert.ToString(i);
    pnlcom1.Controls.Add(chck[i]);
    pnlcom1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

    chckbx[i] = new CheckBox();
    chck[i].ID = string.Format("chk_2_{0}", i);
    chckbx[i].Text = chckbx + Convert.ToString(i);
    pnlcom2.Controls.Add(chckbx[i]);
    pnlcom2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
}
```

You also have used the `CheckBox[]` to build your ID

```
chckbx + Convert.ToString(i);
```

That works seemingly since `Type` + `string` = name of the type + string but looks like:

```
"System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox[]99"
```

So just use the code above

```
string.Format("chk_1_{0}", i);
```